# GetHostEntry casing for machines in different subdomains

Tags: c#, hostname

I have 2 machines calling GetHostEntry to resolve the host name.

Why does GetHostEntry return correct casing for the local machine but when it comes to resolving the host name for a machine in a different sub domain then the casing is wrong and all in lowercase?

Comment: Hostnames are case-insensitive.

Comment: Different name servers, probably.  Could be a unix box for example, following [their common convention](https://tr.opensuse.org/SDB:Why_should_username,_hostname_and_domainname_be_written).